# Getting OpenLayers Vector features vs clusters

Tags: openlayers-2

I am using OpenLayers Vector with a cluster strategy. When I use Vector.features to get the features returned as a list, it returns an array of clusters and not the array of features. This makes the features unable to be addressed individually. Does anyone know how can I get the features list while using the clustering strategy? Any help is appreciated.

(Eg. If there are 5 features in my KML which are clustered as 1, then I get vector.features.length=1. I need the original features list which will have a length of 5)

Below is the implementation of my Vector:

```
var maps_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("KML", {
                     strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Cluster()],
                     protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                        url: "kml/maps.kml",
                        format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
                           extractStyles: true, 
                           extractAttributes: true,
                        })
                    })
                 })

thesis.events.register("loadend", this, function(){
      var my_array = maps_layer.features; //Size of this is = no.of Clusters and not features
});
```

Here is the documentation: http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Vector-js.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [features](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/doc/devdocs/files/OpenLayers/Strategy/Cluster-js.html#OpenLayers.Strategy.Cluster.features) property of cluster strategy object. In [this](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/strategy-cluster.html) example you can fetch all features of layer using the following syntax: `map.layers[1].strategies[1].features.length`.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's an old question, i am putting here another answer/way by which I get the clustered features.

For this solution, you must first get the layer from map. Once getting layer you can access the features of this clustered layer as,
`layer[0].features[0].cluster[0]` 
To understand its structure just log it to console and use `firebug` to view the log.

To make it more useful(as some features may be clustered and some may not) use the simple `if` condition as,

```
    for(var i=0;i<layer[0].features.length;i++){
    if(layer[0].features[i].cluster){
        //cluster exist. play with clustered features
    }else{
        //no clusters. directly access the feature
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In openlayers 5 when trying to style icons I had to do

```
getIconStyle = function(feature) {
  if(feature.getProperties().features.length > 1) {
     //cluster
  } else {
     //no clusters
  }
}

layer = new VectorLayer({
        source: clusterSource,
        visible: false,
        style:getIconStyle
    });
```